# Could hardware RAM disks (with battery) have any benefit in database servers?

Tags: performance, query-performance, index-tuning, memory, performance-tuning

For database servers with many writes, I am wondering why can't these ramdisk/ramdrive be a solution to avoid wearing out SSDs and to avoid losing data if too much is kept in normal ram.
Can these have any benefit at all for db servers ?

[image]

Comment: What if the battery dies?

Comment: Then data will be collected again :) Avoiding data loss is not critical. But I am curious on why these are not used for db servers. Other than the battery risk.

Comment: Of course, but my point is they couldn't replace more durable storage like an SSD, albeit interesting nonetheless. 

Comment: @J.D. Yes, the battery could die, but so could an SSD.  These batteries are designed to be durable. And enterprise SSDs also contain capacitors in case of power failure, for the same reason. Normally these RAMdisks are backed by a regular drive, so it's just used as a cache. It's mainly because RAM is much more expensive than SSDs that we don't use RAMdisks.

Comment: @Charlieface The capacitors aren't there to realistically prevent data loss, and an electrical engineer could explain the actual reasoning behind them. Despite cost per space differences, you can't discount the higher durability of an SSD than RAM. In fact, a big sell of SSDs over HDDs was the improved durability (since there's less moving parts / lack of spinning platters now). RAM which doesn't persist data, is definitely more susceptible to data loss even with a backup battery than an SSD is. But yes, there is also the limitation on how much RAM one can put into a machine realistically too.

Comment: But ... as far as I know, ram can endure more read/writes and do not wear up as [much as] an SSD. Since people do not address this, I guess it's less common. But for example an SSD I have in a db server with constant read/writes, went to 30% wear in 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with a RAM disk is that if it fails (or if just turned off), then everything in it just *disappears*, like the morning mist.

You say that your data "`will be collected again`", but *into what*?

```
Database != File
```

In order to store data, the database process needs to have a *Data File* in which to put "stuff" and that Data File has to be formatted in a way that the database can make use of it.
If the RAM disk has been *wiped clean*, then the file that used to be there is gone ("Solid, Gone!")  There is *nowhere* for the database to store the incoming data - in all likelihood, the database won't even *start up*, because it has a great big "hole" where one of it's Data Files *used* to be!

Answer (score 1):

I was routinely using RAM disks for various DBs - always to some degree "read only". Mainly for analytical or design  purposes, in certain cases for production as well as part of load balancing structures.

These days (09/2023) I use RAM disks very rarely as there is a lot of solution how to run a lot of DB related tasks in memory natively. The simplest example would be in memory SQLite DB; where is easy to explore what is the difference between complex nested queries with 1 million or more records on HDD/SDD vs RAM. Another reason why I do not use the RAM disks so frequently as in past is that current technology evolving fast and the speed difference between RAM and a classic storage(s) is lesser every day.

The difference between latest RAM and latest storage is still 1:30 but not 1:10000 or more as it was in 10 - 15 years ago.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).